# Unable to access service in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I've got this webserver config:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webserver
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: webserver
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: webserver
        image: nginx:alpine
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: hostvol
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
      volumes:
      - name: hostvol
        hostPath:
          path: /home/docker/vol
```

and this web service config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web-service
  labels:
    run: web-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: webserver
```

I was expecting to be able to connect to the webserver via `http://192.168.99.100:80` with this config but Chrome gives me a `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

I tried `minikube service --url web-service` which gives `http://192.168.99.100:30276` however this also has a `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

Any further suggestions?

UPDATE

I updated the port / targetPort to 80.

However, I now get:

`ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` for http://192.168.99.100:80/

and

an nginx `403` for http://192.168.99.100:31540/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your service, you can define a nodePort

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web-service
  labels:
    run: web-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 32700
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: webserver
```

Now, you will be able to access it on http://:32700

Be careful with port 80. Ideally, you would have an nginx ingress controller running on port 80 and all traffic will be routed through it. Using port 80 as nodePort will mess up your deployment.

Comment: Hmm - that seemed to be the issue. Rather confusing having port, targetPort and nodePort.

Answer (score 0):

In your service, you did not specify a targetPort, so the service is using the `port` value as targetPort, however your container is listening on 80. Add a `targetPort: 80` to the service.

Comment: I added targetPort but still can't access the service. Odd.

Comment: Assuming 31540 is your allocated node port, then it looks like the call is making it to nginx, but failing there. You can check the nginx access logs and see if you're hitting the webserver. If you're, then the problem looks like an nginx configuration problem.

Comment: You've got a 403 response. That means you successfully accessed your nginx. Use `kubectl logs` command to see the error log of the nginx to investigate the reason of 403.

Answer (score 0):

NodePort port range varies from 30000-32767(default). When you expose a service without specifying a port, kubernetes picks up a random port from the above range and provide you.

You can check the port by typing the below command

`kubectl get svc`

In your case - the application is port forwarded to 31540. Your issues seems to be the niginx configuration. Check for the nginx logs.

Answer (score 0):

Please check permissions of mounted volume **/home/docker/vol**

To fix this you have to make the mounted directory and its contents publicly readable:

chmod -R o+rX **/home/docker/vol**